# Init startup script ordering

Tags: init-script, sysvinit

In the `/etc/rc5.d` directory there are example 2 shells to be executed on boot. `S02dbus-1` and `S20syslog`. From my understanding `S02dbus-1` will be executed first. Now if I take a look at the shell script of `S02dbus-1` the header says `# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog`.
Does this mean syslog should already be running in order to start the dbus script ? If this is the case how come syslog will be executed after dbus ?
Is there also an easy way to visualise the boot process ? So I can easily see which scripts get executed when and when scripts are executed in parallel.

Comment: You are assuming that that _is_ your boot process.  Depending from the operating system, these may have nothing to do with it at all.  You need to explain in the question how you know that you are using van Smoorenburg `rc`, or at the very least mention the name and version of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) can help you visualize your boot process, outputting graphs that show which processes start when and where they are running in parallel. Here is an example of a bootchart diagram:
[image: A Bootchart]

The project provides a nice [basic guide](http://www.bootchart.org/docs.html) to help users get started.

Depending on your system, the startup order may not follow the names of the /etc/rc files at all, as this behavior is often determined by the rc system, which is conventionally invoked at /etc/init.d/rc. For example, a system using startpar and insserv would determine boot order from the /etc/init.d/.depend.[boot|start|stop] files.